# How do you forward fill in pandas within a group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame of the form

| quarter | user_id | # Sessions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 Q1 | 1 | 9 |
| 2021 Q4 | 1 |  |
| 2021 Q3 | 1 |  |
| 2022 Q1 | 2 | 8 |
| 2021 Q4 | 2 |  |
| 2021 Q3 | 2 |  |

And I'd like to forward fill the # Sessions column within each user_id to get a table like:

| quarter | user_id | # Sessions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 Q1 | 1 | 9 |
| 2021 Q4 | 1 | 9 |
| 2021 Q3 | 1 | 9 |
| 2022 Q1 | 2 | 8 |
| 2021 Q4 | 2 | 8 |
| 2021 Q3 | 2 | 8 |

I can do this with

```py
x.groupby('user_id').apply(lambda x: x.fillna({'# Sessions': x['# Sessions'].ffill()}))
```

But I have reasonably big data (~10k users), and this is a very common operation in the codebase.

Is `.groupby` necessary or is there a more performant way to achieve the same?

Comment: Why not just `x = x.ffill()`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify, not all users have a value on the top row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can avoid use groupby, First we use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html),
Then we just use ffill except for the rows where `user_id` change occurs.

```
df2 = df.sort_values('user_id')
df['# Sessions'] = df2['# Sessions'].ffill()\
    .where(df2['user_id'].eq(df2['user_id'].shift()),
           df2['# Sessions'])
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be much faster than what you're doing:

```
x['# Sessions'] = x.groupby('user_id')['# Sessions'].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try transforming `first` (since `first` skips NaNs):

```
df['# Sessions'] = df.groupby('user_id')['# Sessions'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
   quarter  user_id  # Sessions
0  2022 Q1        1         9.0
1  2021 Q4        1         9.0
2  2021 Q3        1         9.0
3  2022 Q1        2         8.0
4  2021 Q4        2         8.0
5  2021 Q3        2         8.0
```